# Cloudflare removes style attribute of image

Tags: image, cloudflare

Hi I started using cloudflare on my web, but I have serious issues with img tags which have attributes. After loading page all img tags are replaced with cloudflare version, but all attributes(for example style attributes) are removed. Does anyone have similar problems?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it would probably be an issue with Mirage. Do you have that turned on in your performance settings? If yes, try turning that off.

Comment: i was having the same issue as OP, and turning off Mirage helped resolve it for me! thank you!